# Correct structure for __init__.py hierarchy in Python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, init, python-module

So I've seen quite a few answers all over the place about the `__init__.py` file and, to be honest, it's all very confusing to me and I'm not really getting it, so I'm hoping for some help/basic explanation.

I have a package set up as follows:

```
top_package/
├── __init__.py
└── mid_package/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── first_import.py
    └── bottom_package/
         ├── __init__.py
         └── second_import.py
```

So I have a few issues here...

How do I import `first_import.py` in `second_import.py`?

Next, how do I import `second_import.py` in `first_import.py`?

Finally, if I have a script outside of this whole hierarchy, say like this:

```
docs/
├── scripts
|   └── test_script.py
└── top_package/
```

How would I import `first_import.py` and `second_import.py` in `test_script.py`?

My Python version is 3.4.5 (64-bit Anaconda) and I'm running on Windows, if that makes a difference.

So with those questions out of the way, I'll provide a little context on what I've tried so far:

(1) I initialized each `__init.py` with its "level", such as this in the "top" `__init__.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Path\To\top_package")
```

(2) I added a line with `__all__` and an array of everything on that level, for example:

```
__all__ = ['mid_package']
```

(3) Then I added relative imports such as:

```
from .mid_package import first_import
```

Or:

```
from .. import first_import
```

(4) Then I would try to load these normally in files such as this in `second_import.py`:

```
import first_import
```

(5) Next, in `test_script.py`, I would try to load as:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../top_package/')
import first_import
```

Which would result in `ImportError: No module named 'first_import'`.

I'm up for any and all ideas, I've been working on this for a few hours now and just can't seem to crack it. Thanks so much!

Comment: use absolute import. `from top_package.mid_package import first_import` and `from top_package.mid_package.bottom_package import second_import`

Comment: @Sraw In the `__init__.py` files or in outside files?

Comment: @Sraw doing such with the outside files does not work, regardless of it being put it with or without `sys.path.append('../top_package/')` (if there are no edits to the current `__init__.py` files as outlined above.

Comment: Everything you need to know: http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an old question about the structure of a python project. But I think the critical problem is that your current working directory is not the `top_package`. So when your interpreter want to search `top_package`, it is beyond the scope.

This is not a good practice, you should always launch your project with a script located in root directory. A well-constructed python project should like the following example:

```
project
----src
--------app.py
--------modules
------------__init__.py
------------module.py
----test
--------test_cases.py
----doc
--------document.md
----.gitignore
----license.txt
----readme.md
```

And you should always launch your project by `python src/app.py`, then you can use `absolute import` properly.

Notice that this is just a very basic example.

Comment: er no, always use `python -m` or `setup.py`-generated scripts